# How to conver adjacency matrix to graph ruby?

Tags: ruby, shortest-path

I want to find the shortest path of Node x to Node y in Ruby

So i have some code which i got from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Ruby
but i will need the following format of my Graph to work:
[image]

What's the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your input is contained in an array, which I assume is as follows.

```
arr = [[nil,   3,   10,  7,   8, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
       [  3, nil, nil, nil,   6, nil,   9,   5, nil, nil],
       [ 10, nil, nil,   5, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil],
       [  7, nil, nil, nil,   4,   5, nil, nil, nil, nil],
       [  8,   6, nil,   4, nil,   3,   4, nil, nil,   5],
       [nil, nil, nil,   5,   3, nil, nil, nil, nil,   7],
       [nil,   9, nil, nil,   4, nil, nil,   6,   8,   6],
       [nil,   5, nil, nil, nil, nil,   6, nil,  11, nil],
       [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil,   8,  11, nil,   3],
       [nil, nil, nil, nil,   5,   7,   6, nil,   3, nil]]
```

You could then write

```
arr.each_with_index.with_object([]) { |(row, i), a| row.each_with_index { |v, j|
  a << [i, j, v] unless v.nil? } }
    #=> [[0, 1, 3], [0, 2, 10], [0, 3, 7], [0, 4, 8], [1, 0, 3], [1, 4, 6],
    #    [1, 6, 9], [1, 7, 5], [2, 0, 10], [2, 3, 5], [3, 0, 7], [3, 4, 4],
    #   ...
    #    [8, 7, 11], [8, 9, 3], [9, 4, 5], [9, 5, 7], [9, 6, 6], [9, 8, 3]]
```

I've assumed the cells that do not correspond to links equal `nil`. You could use `Float::INFINITY` (in which case we'd write `a << [i, j, v] if v < Float::INFINITY`), but `nil` is more convenient.

See [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index), [Enumerator#with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object). The block variables in `|(row, i), a|` are as follows:

- `row` is an element of `arr`, a 10-element array.
- `i` is the row index (`0`-`9`).
- `a` is an initially-empty array (`each_with_object([])`) that will be build and returned by the block.